# Titanium Appcelerator - Webview issue/bug

Tags: webview, titanium

I have some strange bug in the Titanium...
I have a window, I added a webview to the window.
Now,when I close the window & then coming back to the window
the webview is gone... :-(

Anyone ideas??

Thanks

Code:

```
var main = Titanium.UI.createWindow({....});
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({...});
main.add(webview);
```

Now after those declarations:

```
main.close();
```

and after this:

```
main.open();
```

somehow the main window losing the webview...

Comment: The code is up there mate,thanks

Comment: Try to use hide method instead of close.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
main.relase(webview);
```

before closing and then add again on opening.

or just hide as MZ suggested.